# When should I use xhtml and when xml with xslt?

Tags: xml, xhtml

This is maybe the stupid question, but I am missing the point.

I try to get more into xml and xhtml. I am reading the book and I understand the context of both "languages". For me it seems that you can achieve the same goal with both techniques. It seems that it does not matter if you use xthml + css or xml + xslt, you can create the same web page.

I always thought that xml serves as data source. I know that Xhtml means more clear presentation based on xml rules but have xml some additional purpose? I mean, is there any recommendations when to use xhtml or xml (or use xml as some metadata for xhtml, I don't know some speed reasons or etc.)??

Thanks for answer.

Best Regards,

Juraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason to use xml+xslt for displaying information in the browser is to allow users to easily view XML documents when:

1. the purpose of making such XML documents available is primarily to allow users to process the raw XML in whatever way they want; and
2. display in the browser is primarily for the purpose of allowing the user to preview that data.

If you just want to show stuff to your users in a browser, it will almost certainly be easier to stay away from XSLT (it's not at all fun to programme).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks - going to be a bit simplistic.

1. XML - A way of describing data by tagging it etc. e.g. `<car colour="red">mustang</car>`
2. XHTML - Just using XML with a limited list of tags. e.g. This bit is the `<title>`
3. XSLT - A XML document to describe how to convert a XML document into another form
4. CSS - Lets make it pretty. Put that header there in green, etc...

Comment: thanks for answers, i guess that i  was looking for some complications which is not there at all.

Comment: @Serv0 - The is a difference between the data and its presentation.

Answer (score 0):

When you send xhtml to a browser you tell it "here's some stuff, render it for me".  With XML and XSLT you send it the data (xml) and a "recipe" (xslt) how to transform these data into something renderable.  After that, render it.  Although the end result is the same (a rendered page in a browser) the underlying philosophy is radically different.

One argument to send xml+xslt might be that you decrease the workload to the client, because typically in a scenario where you send xhtml your server has to fetch data somewhere and combine that with some kind of template to create the complete xhtml.

For some of the other arguments I think you may be confused by the parallel HTML vs XHTML debate.  XHTML is a redefinition of HTML to make it XML compatible (eg by forcing open-close tag pairs - think `<BR>` in HTML vs `<br/>`  in XHTML).